# Knitting progress in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I have a shiny application that I used to call the `rmarkdonw::render()` function. I want to be able to show the knitting progress using the `withProgress()` function like here: https://gallery.shinyapps.io/085-progress/

The problem is I don't know how to get the progress status from 'render()' function. Any ideas?